Lines connecting points on a euclidean plane (Does it contain the two shortest segments?)
Imagine you have 3 points with three strait lines connecting them. These lines have weights that are equal to their lengths. When finding the path that you can move along and that connects all points (meaning each point will have two lines connected to it except for the start and end point, which have only one) in the setup with 3 points you will find that the shortest path will be through the two shortest lines. Does it always contain the two shortest segments for any amount of points? From what I can tell it does but I can't find anything online that confirms it.
Please note that the start and end are not designated beforehand.
I'm sorry if this didn't make sense. Please ask clarifying questions and I'll try to respond as quickly as possible.

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the smallest Hamiltonian path in a complete euclidean graph and wondering if this path will always contain the two shortest edges.
This is not true in general. Not even if we only consider the smallest edge. A counterexample on 5 points:
$$ P = [ (0,0), (1,3), (-1,3), (7,7), (-7,7) ] $$
The shortest Hamiltonian path has length $\approx 20.7$ while using the edge of length 2 gives a path of length $\approx 22.3$.


Thank you! This helps a lot. One more thing, you proved it didn’t work for five and higher points what about four?
